# Moving a linked site contained in a Facebook post

Tags: facebook, links

Several people shared a Facebook link to a temporary site I was running. I will be taking this site offline soon as I have the permanent one in place. Is there any way to get Facebook to update the links in these posts to the new address?

Comment: Why do so many questions on "Web Applications" get downvoted? If you are going to downvote at least indicate why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. As far as I know, Facebook doesn't do anything with an "HTTP 301 - Moved permanently" error code (unlike Google Search).

If you can't leave a redirect behind, I'm afraid you're going to have to rely on the people who posted those links changing them.